# Python - missing positional argument

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I am trying to learn a bit about threading by building some code  that will maintain a list and eventually send values from that list to a to-be-created function.    When I call `QueryReport.add` I get the error `TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'`.  I am trying to pass in `report` and `user` list values.  It is my belief the `add` method needs `self` but that `self` for some reason seems to be throwing off the call I made because now I dont have the right number of positional aruguments.  In many other code examples I see methods defined with `self` and two other values with the idea that when the mthod is called two values are passed.  Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?  Since I cant get past this syntax error, is there anything else as blantly wrong?

```
from threading import *

class QueueReport(Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.reports_to_call = []

  def add(self, report, user):
    self.reports_to_call.append([report, user])
    print("Added Value")

  def run(self):
    print("Running")
    #print(reports_to_call)
    #will loop and send values from this list to another function


if __name__ == '__main__':
  t1 = QueueReport()
  t1.run()

  QueueReport.add("mainreport", "user")
```

Comment: `add` should be called on `t1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to add to the class `QueueReport` instead of the instance of the class `t1`. When you call the function on the class, there is no `self` so it treats `"mainreport"` as `self` and `"user"` as `report`.

What you want to do is `t1.add("mainreport", "user")`.

The wrinkle is, if `run` is an infinite loop it will block execution and `t1.add` will never happen.

What you can do is create a separate thread for `t1.run`.

```
from threading import Thread
thread = Thread(target=t1.run)
thread.start()
t1.add("mainreport", "user")
```

Edit: silly me, I did not see that you were already using threading.

Comment: good point on infinaite loop...  i reallty want `run` to be what has its own thread...

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Class method instead of using the instantiation of the class.

Because of that, self is not given to the method, hence missing a parameter.

Try doing `t1.add("mainreport", "user")`